# How to pass angular expression as parameter to normal JS functions?

Tags: angularjs

I have an omniture tracking function name as s.tl(parameter 1, parameter 2, parameter 3) which is written in Normal JS code. I want to call that normal JS function on buy now button click and pass Angular expression as third parameter to that function.

So I am using ng-click as below:

```
<a class="button" href="documentdownloader.aspx?documentid={{document.DownloadLink}}" ng-click="s.tl(true, 'd',{{document.DocumentTitle}})">Buy now </a>
```

But getting below error

```
Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 17 of the expression [s.tl(true, 'd',{{document.DocumentEnglishTitle}});] starting at [{document.DocumentEnglishTitle}});].
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the curly braces in your `ng-click`, because in `ng-click` you are already evaluating the angular expression :

```
<a class="button" href="documentdownloader.aspx?documentid={{document.DownloadLink}}" ng-click="s.tl(true, 'd',document.DocumentTitle)">Buy now </a>
```

Comment: If we remove the curly braces then we don't get the evaluated value. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I just realized the place where you have error is not the same as the code you posted. Where is `document.DocumentEnglishTitle`? It's not the same as `document.DocumentTitle`

Comment: even we have corrected that still we getting same error.

Comment: you will need to check if your `document.DownloadLink` really exist in your controller as `$scope.document.DownloadLink` or not. If there is such $scope variable, there is no way the error would be thrown like that.